# Select 5 latest rows of each column pair

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I've got a big table (>1m. rows) with a structure similar to this one:

| ID | foreign_key_1 | foreign_key_2 | clicks | installs | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01 | 01 | 2 | 0 | 2022-11-10 |
| 2 | 01 | 02 | 54 | 12 | 2022-11-10 |
| 3 | 01 | 01 | 9 | 0 | 2022-11-11 |
| 4 | 01 | 02 | 85 | 20 | 2022-11-11 |
| 5 | 01 | 01 | 3 | 1 | 2022-11-12 |
| 6 | 01 | 02 | 8 | 0 | 2022-11-12 |
| 7 | 01 | 01 | 6 | 0 | 2022-11-13 |
| 8 | 01 | 02 | 221 | 60 | 2022-11-13 |
| 9 | 01 | 01 | 61 | 10 | 2022-11-14 |
| 10 | 01 | 02 | 75 | 17 | 2022-11-14 |
| 11 | 01 | 01 | 58 | 8 | 2022-11-15 |
| 12 | 01 | 02 | 9 | 0 | 2022-11-15 |
| 13 | 01 | 01 | 10 | 1 | 2022-11-16 |
| 14 | 01 | 02 | 25 | 0 | 2022-11-16 |

How would I be able to select the latest 5 rows of every unique pair of foreign_key_1 and foreign_key_2, based on their created_at dates? And is that even possible?

I've tried experimenting with partitions and grouping but I'm a begginer at writing mySQL syntax and complex queries so I haven't been able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution would be to use the `row_number()` window function where you partition by `foreign_key_1` and `foreign_key_2`, and order the partitions by `created_at` in descending order:

```sql
with row_nums as (
  select
    *,
    row_number() over (
      partition by foreign_key_1, foreign_key_2 order by created_at desc
    ) as rn
  from your_table
)

select *
from row_nums
where rn <= 5
```